# Red bus test cases

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, testcase

1.Write Test cases for the Scenario - On an ecommerce site, A logged in Customer can place order for more than 10 or more items with free shipping free. For less than 10 items purchased, customer is charged Rs. 100 for order value less than Rs. 10000 and Rs. 1000 for more than Rs. 10000.

2.Automate to get number of buses available by Passing values From City, Destination City and Date from csv file in the RedBus website. Pass 5 records from file and need to be received same csv data with bus count as result.